# Do a function just one time in only one thread in TPL

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Here is the scenario:

1. I have a proxy that is shared among all the threads.
2. if this proxy gets blocked, then only ONE thread needs to dequeue a proxy from ProxyQueue, not all of them. 
   For dequeuing I am using interlocked right now so only one thread at a time can enter the function.

   ```
               private static volatile string httpProxy = "1.1.1.1";
               private static int usingResource = 0;
               string localHttpProxy;

                 try
         {
                                                                                      HttpWebRequest oReqReview =         HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);                                                          
   if (IsHttpProxyDequeue)
    {
   oReqReview.Proxy = new WebProxy(httpProxy, 8998);
    localHttpProxy = httpProxy;

        }
   HttpWebResponse respReview = (HttpWebResponse)oReqReview.GetResponse();
   DoSomthing();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   if (0 == Interlocked.Exchange(ref usingResource, 1))
   {

   if (ex.Message == "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." &&      httpProxy     == localHttpProxy)
   {
                                                                                              IsHttpProxyDequeue =     currentQueueProxy.TryDequeue(out httpProxy);

   }
   Interlocked.Exchange(ref usingResource, 0);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working for you?

Comment: this code is not working as I described. Just wondering if multiple threads reach interlocked, do they wait until interlock become available? if yes, then getproxy function repeats multiple time

Comment: What do you mean by "if this proxy gets blocked"?

Comment: This proxy cant work anymore. 403 Forbidden Error

Answer (score 2):

Interlocked.Exchange does not block. It merely performs the swap of the value and reports the results.  If the initial value of `usingResource` is 0 and three threads hit `Interlocked.Exchange` at exactly the same time, on one thread the Exchange() will return zero and set usingResource to 1, and on the other two threads Exchange() will return 1.  Threads 2 and 3 will immediately continue executing with the first statement following the if block.

If you want threads 2 and 3 to block waiting for thread one to finish, then you should use something like a mutex lock, like the C# `lock(object)` syntax.  Locks block threads.

`Interlocked.Exchange` does not block threads.  `Interlocked.Exchange` is useful when writing non-blocking thread coordination. `Interlocked.Exchange` says "If I get the special value from this swap I'll take a detour and do this special operation, otherwise I'll just continue doing this other thing without waiting."

Comment: Great explanation! Then interlocked is exactly what I am looking for. I dont want other threads to wait. I used mutext before interlocked and in my scenario it was not useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `Interlocked` does provide synchronization on that value, so if multiple threads reach that point at the same time, only one of them will get a `0` back. All others will get a `1` back until the value gets set back to '0'.

You have a race condition in your code, which is probably what's causing the problem. Consider this sequence of events:

```
Thread A sees that `IsProxyDequeue` is `false`
Thread A calls `Interlocked.Exchange` and gets a value of '0'
Thread A logs the error
Thread B sees that `IsProxyDequeue` is `false`
Thread A dequeues the proxy and sets `usingResource` back to `0`
Thread B calls `Interlocked.Exchange` and gets a value of `0`
```

At this point, Thread B is also going to dequeue the proxy.

You'll need to come up with a different way of providing the synchronization. I suspect you'll want something like:

```
object lockObj = new object();
lock (lockObj)
{
    if (!IsProxyDequeue)
    {
        // get the proxy
        IsProxyDequeue = true;
    }
    oReqReview.Proxy = new   WebProxy(httpProxy, 8989);
}
```

If you want to avoid the race condition, but you don't want other threads to block, then use `Monitor.TryEnter` rather than `lock`.

Comment: This is one of the scenarios that caused a problem. I am using getproxy in the catch statement, so how can I apply your logic there?

Comment: You'll have to show some code. I don't have the context to interpret what "in the catch statement" is referring to.

Comment: what is the type of isProxyDequeue? is it volatile? if yes, this code only works for the first IP. how about next round when second IP gets blocked!!? where should I reset the IsProxyDequeue?